# mysql not returning results when making a concat like comparison

Tags: mysql

I am building a query in MySQL to get records where soundex of a particular column is like soundex of a given value

I am submitting this query:

```
select nombre_busqueda, 
       soundex(nombre_busqueda), 
       soundex('derticia'), 
       concat('%', (soundex(nombre_busqueda)) , '%')  
from jugador j 
WHERE idjugador=472
```

And getting the following

```
nombre_busqueda
dertycia oscar alberto alvarez

soundex(nombre_busqueda)
D632641634162

soundex('derticia')
D632

concat('%', (soundex(nombre_busqueda)) , '%')
%D632641634162%
```

So it looks like perfect to make the comparison and get the results.
But when I issue the following query:

```
select nombre_busqueda, 
       soundex(nombre_busqueda), 
       soundex('derticia'), 
       concat('%', (soundex(nombre_busqueda)) , '%')  
from jugador j WHERE 
soundex('derticia') like concat('%', (soundex(nombre_busqueda)) , '%')
```

Nothing gets returned!
What I am doing wrong? It looks like pretty obvious to me that should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interchange the parameters on either side of the `LIKE`:

```
select nombre_busqueda, 
       soundex(nombre_busqueda), 
       soundex('derticia'), 
       concat('%', (soundex(nombre_busqueda)) , '%')  
from jugador j 
WHERE soundex(nombre_busqueda) like concat('%', soundex('derticia') , '%')
```

Comment: @user2954295 happy to help :) Do consider marking it as accepted answer (green tick). Thanks :)